# Limit of $(1-f(n))^n$ where $f(n)\sim n^\alpha$

Tags: analysis, limits, asymptotics

What is the limit of
$(1-f(n))^n$ where $f(n)$ is a positive function of $n$, asymptotically equivalent to $n^\alpha$ for some $\alpha <0$, i.e. $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(n)}{n^\alpha}=1$. For example, if $f(n) = 1/n$, then the limit is known to be $1/e$. Is there a generalization of this result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the assumption $\alpha < 0$, then $\log [(1-f(n))^n] = n \log (1-f(n)) \sim -n f(n) \sim -n^{1+\alpha}$.  So if $\alpha < -1$, $(1-f(n))^n \to 1$; if $\alpha = -1$, $(1-f(n))^n \to 1/e$; and if $-1 < \alpha < 0$, then $(1-f(n))^n \to 0$.  If $\alpha \ge 0$, the only way for the expression to make sense for large $n$ is $f(n) \to 1^-$, $\alpha = 0$, and then $(1-f(n))^n \to 0$.

Comment: It is stated $\alpha < 0$ indeed.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you want $\alpha<0$. Then
$$\ln\left[(1-f(n))^n
\right]=n\ln(1-f(n))=-nf(n)+O(nf(n)^2)\sim -n^{1+\alpha}$$
etc.